# Issue saving Latin characters on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, unicode, varchar

I'm having an issue when saving text data to a SQL Server 2019 database using Latin_General_CI_AS as the default collation. The column in question is set as varchar. When the client types a word like **`não`** it saves normally with no issue, but if he copy+paste the word it saves as **`n~ao`**. Debugging I found out that when copy pasting instead of using the unicode character "ã" it uses a combining diacritical mark "~" plus the letter "a", and looks like varchar can't handle it.

I already saw that changing to nvarchar might solve the issue, but I would need to do it on a lot of columns, is there any other way around this issue other than changing the column data type?

Comment: I don't think this is a SQL Server issue. Sounds like more of a UI issue. SQL Server default character set for VARCHAR seems to handle both `'não'` and `'n~ao'` just fine. See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/laqKxDLl). The VARCHAR type does have limits though. Perhaps the `'~'` character you are getting is not a simple tilde and is a special UNICORN combining character of some sort.

Comment: ... uh, ... "UNICODE" combining character, not .

Comment: Presumably it is `U+0303` and this isn't a character supported in the code page of your collation so it gets converted to regular tilde `U+007E` https://dbfiddle.uk/gcQ1pZD_

Answer (score 2):

Changing the datatype to `nvarchar` is one way to solve it.

Another way to solve this is by changing the settings on your database and/or table by using collation like `Latin_General_CI_AI` for some case-insensitive and accent-insensitive comparisons, which can handle Latin characters well.

Usually `nvarchar` is used because it has a wider range of Latin characters and other non-ASCII characters than `varchar`

Comment: Forgot to add we are already using Latin_General_CI_AI collation

Comment: Then I really do think that  the datatype `nvarchar` is needed rather than using `varchar`